# ASP.NET Limit Login Retries

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am a newbie, I just want to know if someone is familiar with restricting user to a maximum of 3 login attempts only but it fails. Logging on is working well but when I tried to access the web with incorrect password, the counter didn't work. Can someone help me . Here is my code:

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckMember",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@userName",txtUsername.Text.ToString());
            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@password",txtPassword.Text.ToString());
            SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@accountNo",txtAcctNo.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p3); 

            SqlDataReader lmsreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (lmsreader.HasRows)
            {
                lmsreader.Read();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), false);
               // FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text.ToString(), chkboxCookie.Checked);
                lblError.Text = "You got it!";
                Response.Redirect("MyAccount.aspx");
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                this.lblError.Text = "Invalid username, password or account number.<br> Please try again.";
                this.lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                object FailedLoginCounter = this.Page.Cache["UserKey_" + this.txtUsername.Text];
                if (FailedLoginCounter == null)
                {
                    FailedLoginCounter = 0;
                }
                this.Page.Cache["UserKey_" + this.txtUsername.Text] = (int)FailedLoginCounter + 1;
                if (((int)this.Page.Cache["UserKey_" + this.txtUsername.Text]) == 3)
                {

                    SqlConnection conect = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
                    SqlCommand commander = new SqlCommand("MemberIsBlocked", con);
                    commander.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    conect.Open();
                    SqlParameter puser = new SqlParameter("@username", txtUsername.Text.ToString());
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conect.Close();
                    lblError.Text = "You are Temporarily Blocked for <br> Exceeding Max Number of Login Attempts.";
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {

        }

        }

        public string GetConnectionString()
         {

             return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionServices"].ConnectionString;

         }
```

Your help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try using `Session["User_Key" +...]` instead of `this.Page.Cache["User_Key" + ...]`.

Comment: When you say 'the counter didn't work', what exactly do you mean? Have you stepped through this code with the debugger to see exactly what is happening?

Comment: @UweKeim I did a few seconds ago, but still not yet working.

Comment: @patmortech sorry, I mean is, if a user is going to fail to login for 3 consecutive attempts, he/she should be temporary lock and unable to access the website.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375831/how-to-limit-login-attempts .it uses db for limit user attempts,but it may helpful to solve this

Comment: @Gopesh I've tried, and it fails.. I do not know why.

Comment: What kind of 'failure' are you getting?

Comment: What input did you try to see if its working? Your counter will maintain different count for different usernames. And only restrict if you input the same username with 3 wrong password. and that too limited to the session.

Comment: @patmortech the number of retries is not incrementing..

Comment: @Gnani, yes you are right, actually I am using only one username to test..but no luck.maybe you can give me a sample code that is working and show it to me? thanks!

Comment: @Dhenn, Are you getting "Invalid username, password or account number.<br> Please try again." this message for invalid username password?

Comment: yes, i am only getting invalid username,password or account number, I repeat to type incorrect password for more than 3 times yet I am not blocked.

Comment: @UweKeim You shouldn't use Session for this as a user can simply clear cookies to start a new one and reset the counter.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the work...it worked fine for me..

```
   void GetUser(string EmployeeName, string Password)
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        string cmd1 = "select Emp_IsBlocked from dbo.PTS_Employee where Emp_Username='" + EmployeeName + "' and Emp_Password='" + Password + "'";
        SqlCommand mycomm2 = new SqlCommand(cmd1, con2);
        con2.Open();
        Object Blocked = mycomm2.ExecuteScalar();
        con2.Close();
        //Checks Wether the user is blocked or not
        if (Blocked != null)
        {
            //if the use is not blocke it redirects to the specified page
            if (Blocked.ToString() == "")
            {
                Session["EmployeeName"] =EmployeeName;

                Response.Redirect("~/Transactions.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "You are Temporarily Blocked for Exceeding Max Number of Login Attempts";
            }
        }
            //Checks the attempts of the user if the user attempts are more than 3 it blocks him for login again
        else
        {
            object FailedLoginCounter = this.Page.Cache["UserKey_" + this.txtEmpName.Text];
            if (FailedLoginCounter == null)
            {
                FailedLoginCounter = 0;
            }
            this.Page.Cache["UserKey_" + this.txtEmpName.Text] = (int)FailedLoginCounter + 1;
            if (((int)this.Page.Cache["UserKey_" + this.txtEmpName.Text]) == 3)
            {
                SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connstring);
                SqlCommand mycomm1 = new SqlCommand("SP_IsBlocked", con1);
                mycomm1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con1.Open();
                mycomm1.Parameters.Add("@IsBlocked", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Yes";
                mycomm1.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmpName.Text;
                mycomm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con1.Close();
                lblError.Text = "You Exceeded The Maximum Login Attempts of 3,You are Blocked for now....Please Contact your Admin for Reuse Of Your Account";
            }
        }
    }
```

and call the "Getuser" method in your button click

Answer (score 1):

You should use Membership class for this check out this url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx and for detail check [this video](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication/understanding-aspnet-memberships) and for further details on authentication check [this one](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication).

Hope this will help you out.